# Synapse: Automated publishing for continuous integration and delivery without manual publishing ("The new CI/CD flow")

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, cicd

I'm trying to implement a fully automated ci/cd pipeline for my synapse workspace using azure devops piplines. I have a working version where everything except pushing the "Publish" Button inside the synapse UI after merging a feature branch into main is automated, but i cannot figure out how to automate this last step.

Basically I'm at the "Current CI/CD flow" in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements) and i want to implement "the new CI/CD flow", just using Synapse instead of Data Factory.

Sadly, the article marks the described solution as only valid for Data Factory and not for Synapse and I couldn't find anything about using the used ADFUtilities NPM package for Synapse workspaces.

So what is the recommended way for automatically publish all changes after a pull request was merged into the main branch for synapse pipelines? Is there even a way or are we stuck with pressing the "Publish" Button by ourself?

Comment: Did you see the blog "Automating the Publishing of Workspace Artifacts in Synapse CICD" on techcommunity.microsoft.com.

It is long-winded (I haven't gotten thru it all myself).  But I think it accomplishes your goals.  
See:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/automating-the-publishing-of-workspace-artifacts-in-synapse-cicd/ba-p/3603042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Synapse, There is a way to automate the publish action on commit to collaboration branch.

Use "Synapse workspace deployment" extension task version 2.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureSynapseWorkspace.synapsecicd-deploy

More details are in the page:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/automating-the-publishing-of-workspace-artifacts-in-synapse-cicd/ba-p/3603042